# soundcloud streaming IE8

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I can't seem to get the soundcloud API to stream a track in IE8.

Works fine in other browsers (also IE9 and IE10).

[The stream demo on the soundcloud docs](http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/basic.html) also doesn't work for me on IE8

```
...

SC.stream("/tracks/" + _model.id, function(sound) {
    _sound = sound;
    _sound.play({
        whileplaying: onPlaying,
        onpause: onPaused,
        onplay: onPlayed,
        onresume: onPlayed,
        onfinish: onFinished
    });
});

...
```

Or is this a soundmanager problem? When I try to stream I can see the soundmanager file getting requested, and then, nothing more, whereas it should load the flashfallbacks etc. (which it does in IE9 for example)

Is this just unsupported for IE8, or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure out exactly why, but when I include my own soundManager, file, everything works as expected.

My guess is that the soundmanager file gets loaded from another domain, so IE8 can't handle that very well. The tracks on the other hand get loaded through jsonp, which DOES work properly in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental difference between IE8 and IE9+ is [HTML5 audio support](http://caniuse.com/audio).

EDIT: soundmanager has a flashplayer fallback for older browsers.  Do you have flash in IE8? Does [the soundmanager demo](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/play-mp3-links/) work in your IE8